# How to make up lost reference to declare a field (numpy)?

Tags: python, numpy, reference, scientific-computing

Let's say I have class that contains a lot of fields and I want to make initializer that work for all fields so that I don't need to write an initializer for each of them.

```
class Foo():
    def __init__(n):
        self.n = n
        self.x = None
        self.m = None
        self.v = None
```

but method

```
def init_x(self, x):
    # initialize or erase x to zeros
    x = np.zeros(self.n)
```

doesn't work because `x=` loses reference to `x`. But

```
@staticmethod
def get_x(x, i):
    return x[i]

@staticmethod
def set_x(x, i):
    x[i] = val
```

works. What could possibly make my `init_x` to work? I want to set the fields to None initially cuz there are other things that I depend on whether these fields are None or not.

---

Re one of the comment, below doesn't work

```
from numpy import zeros

class Foo:
  def __init__(self):
    self.x = None

  @staticmethod
  def foo(x):
    x[:] = zeros((10,4))

  def make(self):
    self.foo(self.x)


f = Foo()
f.make()
print(f.x)
```

since

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "python", line 16, in <module>
  File "python", line 12, in make
  File "python", line 9, in foo
TypeError: 'NoneType' object does not support item assignment
```

Comment: Are you returning any values in your init_x() method? Or do you want to affect the class-scope `x` variable?

Comment: @Dyno I just want to affect the class-scope x variable, no returning.

Comment: This is very similar to the question you asked recently [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51561710/how-to-initialize-an-object-with-a-field-a-numpy-array-and-the-array-is-passed) (within the hour). Please don't keep posting the same issue in different ways, fix your initial question first.

Comment: If that `init_x(x)` function is inside the class it shouldn't even work since you aren't specifying `self` the first argument

Comment: @RafaelC can you see my update on the question? I tried what you suggested but it didn't work.

Comment: @ZHU with your update, I honestly have no idea what you are trying to accomplish.  You are using a static method to try to slice a nonetype and assign it a numpy array?

Comment: Why not make `make` a one line function that goes `self.x = np.zeros((10, 4))`?

Comment: @user3483203 then how should I achieve the purpose of initializing with None and another initializer `ini_x` will give it a numpy array with zeros?

Comment: Just have another function that goes `self.x = np.zeros(whatever)`.  However, it sounds like your grasping at the `@property` decorator

Comment: @user3483203 I want something that works for many fields since I don't want to define something that just works for one field and then I need many methods like this for each field

Answer (score 0):

The only way I can think of is to march through the variables to figure out which variable it is, then assign it using `self`. Something like this:

```
class Foo():
    def __init__(self,n):
        self.n = n
        self.x = None
        self.m = None
        self.v = None

    def init_x(self, x):
    # initialize or erase x to zeros
        names=self.__dict__.keys()
        varname=[name for name in names if getattr(self,name)==x]
        setattr(self,varname[0],np.zeros(self.n))
```

Answer (score 0):

An initializer for one attribute would be written as:

```
class Foo():
    def __init__(self, n):
        self.n = n
        self.x = None
    def set_x(self):
        self.x = np.zeros(self.n)
    def __repr__(self):
        return 'Foo {} {}'.format(self.n, self.x)

In [67]: f = Foo(3)

In [68]: f
Out[68]: Foo 3 None

In [69]: f.set_x()

In [70]: f
Out[70]: Foo 3 [0. 0. 0.]

In [71]: f.x
Out[71]: array([0., 0., 0.])
```

Maybe this is stating the obvious, but I have to dig through the comments to get a clearer sense that you want to generalize `set_x` to somehow work with a set of attributes.

The attribute can be modified directly:

```
In [72]: f.x = np.zeros((1,f.n),int)

In [73]: f
Out[73]: Foo 3 [[0 0 0]]
```

Once `f.x` is an array we can mutate it.  But this won't work if it is `None`:

```
In [74]: f.x[0,:]=[1,2,3]

In [75]: f
Out[75]: Foo 3 [[1 2 3]]
```

We could access the attribute by string name, via the `__dict__`:

```
In [79]: f.__dict__['x']=None

In [80]: f
Out[80]: Foo 3 None

In [81]: f.__dict__['x']=np.arange(f.n*2)

In [82]: f
Out[82]: Foo 3 [0 1 2 3 4 5]
```

It should be easy to wrap this in a method.

`f.x` is the value of the attribute, and does not, by itself, reference the attribute.  `f.x` in this regard is just like other variables.